# iPython crashes on printing Fibonacci Series

Tags: python, ipython, python-2.x, fibonacci

While attempting to print a fibonacci series using tuples, iPython tends to crash.

Here is the code I am trying to execute.

```
n = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")

a = 0
b = 1
while b < n:
    (b,a) = (a,b+a)
    print b
```

However, if I replace n with a number (eg. 20, 100, 1000), it runs smoothly. I also tried to run this code in Pycharm, with similar results. Pycharm ran the code, with a huge stream on numbers being generated, and a warning which read:

> Too much output to process

What causes this crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to turn the string `n` you get from `raw_input` into an integer.

Since the comparison is done by type name in this case `b < n` will always be `True`.

Use `n = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))`

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware that raw_input needed to be coerced into integer type.

Answer (score 0):

Because the return value of raw_input is str, you should try 
`n = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))` instead.